# Newbie in vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to understand how vectors work. From what I ve read they are a class that can be used as an array with many helpful functions to handle its elements. So I ve tried creating a vector of a class A which contains a vector of class B.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class B
{
  public:
    B()
    {}
    void print()
    {
        cout<<"The mighty ";
    }
    ~B()
    {}
};

class A
{
B b;
vector<B> Blist;
public:
    A()
    {
        cout<<"An A!"<<endl;
    }
    void pushb()
    {
        Blist.push_back(b);
    }
    void printb()
    {
        Blist[7].print();
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout<<"Kass Company"<<endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
    }
      };


int main(void)
{
vector<A> Alist;
A a, b, c;
Alist.push_back(a);
Alist[1].printb();
Alist[1].print();
return 0;   
}
```

Well, my problem is that... it works fine. If vectors work like arrays shouldnt the first object that gets pushbacked get the 0 position of the vector? As a result, shouldnt the program fail to run, since there is no object in the Alist[1] or the Blist[7]?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have stumbled upon one of the most important concepts in C++: Undefined Behaviour. You can read more about it here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: *"shouldnt the program fail to run"*? Maybe yes, maybe no. Accessing a vector out of bounds results in *Undefined Behavior*, which means anything can happen, including the illusion that the program worked fine.

Comment: Use `at` to have bounding check (and so exception you have to catch).

Comment: You might (or might not) observe the exact same behavior if you used arrays instead of `std::vector` since the `[]` operator performs no bounds checking (and accessing out of bounds is *undefined behavior* as already pointed out)

Answer (score 3):

> Well, my problem is that... it works fine

Well, in fact it shouldn't, since you're accessing both `Alist` and `Alist::Blist` out of their bounds.

> If vectors work like arrays shouldnt the first object that gets pushbacked get the 0 position of the vector?

The `std::vector<T>::push_back` function appends an element to the end of the vector, so the push-backed element is given the index `size() - 1` (after the push, e.g. the old `size()`).

#### Check your bounds

When using `std::vector`, *you are responsible* for checking the bounds you're trying to access to. You can use `std::vector<T>::size()` for this check, or the function `std::vector<T>::at(size_t)` as said by Jarod42.
See the STL documentation for more information : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/.

#### Why it seems to work anyway

You're stumbling across undefined behavior but still, it seems to work fine. Why ?

Well, internally the vector holds a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, holding the vector contents. The class encapsulates all the nasty memory management (calling `new`, `delete`, resizing the array, etc.).
When you're calling `std::vector<T>::operator[](size_t)`, by doing for example `Alist[1]`, it simply boils down to dereferencing the internal array at the given index (without bound checking).

Using a bad index, you end up reading some memory past the end of the allocated region, that does not contain any meaningful data, and is probably either uninitialized or zero'ed out. In conclusion when you're doing `Alist[1]`, you're getting some garbage memory interpreted as an `A` instance.

Now why the hell doing `Alist[1].print()` does not crash ? Because the function `A::print()` is not using of the class members, and doing `a->print()` simply does not uses `a` contents.

You can verify this using this program (please don't actually use this, it is just intended for this demonstration) :

```
int foo = 0xDEADBEEF;
A& z = static_cast<A&>(*((A*) &foo));
z.print();
```

This code simply uses the memory occupied by the integer value `foo` as an `A` instance (much like you're using uninitialized memory when accessing the vector out of bounds), and calls the `A::print()` function.

You can try this for yourself, it works as expected ! This is because this member function does not need to use the actual memory content of the instance, and will run no matter `z` points to garbage or not.

#### How to debug and check this program

Use valgrind (http://valgrind.org/). Definitely.
Using `valgrind`'s `memcheck`, you can track down invalid reads and writes (as well as other memory related stuff) :

```
you$ valgrind --tool=memcheck a.out

==1785== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1785== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1785== Using Valgrind-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1785== Command: ./a.out
==1785==
An A!
An A!
An A!
==1785== Invalid read of size 8
==1785==    at 0x400F14: std::vector<B, std::allocator<B> >::operator[](unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:771)
==1785==    by 0x400E02: A::printb() (main.c:34)
==1785==    by 0x400C0D: main (main.c:51)
==1785==  Address 0x5a12068 is 8 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==1785==    at 0x4C28965: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1785==    by 0x4022E5: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<A>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
==1785==    by 0x401D20: std::_Vector_base<A, std::allocator<A> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (in /home/amonti/.local/share/people/temp/a.out)
==1785==    by 0x4013F8: std::vector<A, std::allocator<A> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<A*, std::vector<A, std::allocator<A> > >, A const&) (vector.tcc:345)
==1785==    by 0x401017: std::vector<A, std::allocator<A> >::push_back(A const&) (stl_vector.h:913)
==1785==    by 0x400BF4: main (main.c:50)
==1785==
The mighty Kass Company
==1785==
==1785== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1785==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1785==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 32 bytes allocated
==1785==
==1785== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1785==
==1785== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1785== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 3 from 3)
```

In this trace valgrind detects an invalid read (of size 8 because you're reading a pointer on a 64-bit platform) at `main.c:34` :

```
Blist[7].print();
```

So you can verify that you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

in your case the output maybe a trash result because the logic of the vector data structure is that its a dynamic array that expands it self(by a constant range ) when it reaches the last free space . 
for example when first creating a vector it has 10 spaces when it reaches the 10 space it becomes 20 and in this stage the vec[11] has a trash value.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why you're supposed to use [`vector::at()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) instead of `vector::operator[]` when you're testing/writing your program for the first time.

You can use macros and preprocessor defines to declare that you're compiling for debug, such as:

```
#ifdef THISISDEBUG
    return myvec.at(5);
#else
    return myvec[5];
#endif
```

Then you tell your makefile to `define` `THISISDEBUG` when you're debugging/testing.

The difference between `at()` and `operator[]`, is that `at()` throws an exception if you're out of range, while `operator[]` accesses memory directly.

In C++, you're generally allowed to read any place in memory (at least in Windows and Linux), but you're only allowed to write into places that belong to your program. Your operating system protects you! Imagine you do what you did up there, and you try to modify something that doesn't belong to your proram. Back then in the 80s and 90s, this would've been accepted and would've lead to a blue screen. Now, your operating system raises a [SEGFAULT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

On the other hand, the reason why you're seeing a result there, is because deleting an object doesn't necessarily mean resetting values in memory. It just means that your program tells the operating system: "look, I don't need this region of memory anymore". So, your operating system can assign this region to another program. So, if you try to read that region again, it will work, but you'll get garbage! That's exactly what this technically is called. Like when you do:

```
double x;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

What is the value that will be printed? It's garbage. It's the remnant of some other program that freed that memory.

Comment: "Back then in the 80s and 90s, this would've been accepted and would've lead to a blue screen".
That means that in the 90s with a mistake like that, I could have alter the variables of different programs? :/ Sounds scary :P

Comment: @Bill.G Actually it's scary, but it's how computers started. Actually you can still do this nowadays when you program drivers, like display drivers. I know people that work for the LHC (Large Hadron Collider) in Mainz in Germany who program FPGA units that communicate with high performance display cards (nvidia CUDA and Tesla technologies). They have all these problems still in 2017. 1 mistake, and boom... blue screen!

Comment: Iew. I wouldn't advocate that `#ifdef DEBUG` macro. There's a far more standard idiom: `assert(myvec.size() > 5)`. There's no point in throwing an exception in debug mode only. Throws need a matching `catch`, and again this would be in debug mode only. And what would you do there? Exceptions alter the flow of code, but in debug you want the code to halt at the location of the problem and not somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly vectors are arrays class.

```
vector <string> arr; // defines that this is array
vector <MyClass *> arrw; // defines that this is array to my created class vector
```

Vector is useful to use, when you don't know how much array elements you need. For example, read lines from file. To add new element to vector you can use `arr.insert(arr.end(), "");` and `add.insert(arr.end(), new MyClass);` (I like this better then `push_back`, becouse You can insert in any place of vector.)

You can access you array element by the same way:

```
arr[2];
```

Also it's useful to know some tricks like get access to last element; `arr[arr.size() - 1] i`. (arr.size() will return INT [elements in array]. And -1 will count it for good index. Othewise you will get segmentation error).

P.S. There is no difference between vector Class and array, ecxept this methods, that allow add new elements, when you don't know how big your array will be.

Comment: I believe there's a pretty big difference between an array and a vector. What do you base that on?

Comment: If I can both get by typing `arr[0]`, I don't see difference. I don't see neccessory to explore what's behind vectors, if it's wirking similar way.

Comment: Strong disagreement. A key point is that `vector` can change its size, unlike arrays. It can grow and shrink. That means a given index `[i]` may be correct at some times, and not at others. With an array, either an index `[i]` is valid or it's not, and that doesn't change for the lifetime of the array.